# How to grab certain elements of an input?

Tags: c++, arrays

For a project I'm working on, I want to convert a letter to a number (like A = 20). So I want to be able to take "AQJD" and convert that to a number. How do I take what a user inputted and grab certain elements.

Something as simple as

```
char myArray [] = "AQJD"
```

can be grabbed like so:

```
myArray[0] // this will return A because A is the 0th element
```

but how can I get what a user inputted to do something like what's above. I tried to do this (pasted below) but it wouldn't work.

```
string x; //assume I included <string> already
cout << "Please input what you would like to change: " << endl;
cin >> x;
char mine [] = x;
cout << mine[2] << endl;
```

Is there a way to pass a variable to an array like I tried above?

Comment: Space entered by user become delimiter. I think that better would be reading from stdin using [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` already has an `operator[]` function that returns the character at the specified position. It's exactly the same as a regular char array:

```
cout << x[2]; // J
```

Comment: Thank you! Sounds too simple to be true haha

Answer (score 0):

You may use `.c_str()` method of `std::string` that is quite similar:

```
const char *mine = x.c_str();
cout << mine[2] << endl;
```